# How can I produce a fatal error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to trigger the command line option [--report-on-fatalerror](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/cli.html#cli_report_on_fatalerror).

Like this: `node --report-on-fatalerror app.js`.

It is about a fatal error, not about an uncaught exeption!

Uncaught exception is quite simple:

```
process.once('uncaughtException', function (error) {
  console.error('Uncaught exception:' , error);
});
 
throw new Error('myError');
```

[image: console output]

How to get a harmless fatal error in Node.js?

Already tried with sytnaxerror and reference error. But they are detected at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have NodeJS produce a fatal error is by running out of memory.

There's a [V8 option to set the old memory section](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes). Most variables in a running program are stored there.

```
node --max-old-space-size=1
```

On my machine anything under 5mb will make Node instantly crash (or rather after the first garbage collection), with a different error for 1-2mb, 3mb and 4mb. Simply running:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4 --report-on-fatalerror
ls -l report*
```

Will generate a report.[date].json file.

Relying on a magic number like "4" is iffy and perhaps you want to control *when* it crashes. You can just set the value low enough to not crash instantly and then allocate enough memory to trigger a garbage collector that hits the limit, eg:

```sh
# Enough memory to not instantly crash
# -e evaluates a script that allocates some memory.
# It logs every loop iteration.
node --max-old-space-size=10 --report-on-fatalerror -e 'a=[];for(i=0;i<1024**2;i++)console.log(i),a.push(String(i).repeat(10000))'

ls -l report*
```

Comment: It's a fatalerror ;-)