# Is it possible to change the Node heap size

Tags: node.js

I want to increase the Node (`version 16.20.2`) size, the current size is 70M+, so I add the configuration like this to increase to 256M:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=256"
```

After I start the application use this script, the Node heap size still did not change; this is the startup shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export HOST=0.0.0.0
export PORT=1234
export YPERSISTENCE=/opt/data/yjs-storage
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=256"

nohup node --inspect ./bin/server.js >> ws.log 2>&1 &
nohup node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./bin/http_server.js >> http.log 2>&1 &

tail -f ws.log
```

Am I missing something? is it possible to change the Node size?

Answer (score 1):

It actually looks right. I once had a similar question [How can I produce a fatal error in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077928/how-can-i-produce-a-fatal-error-in-node-js). So it's possible.

I think you reset the option by the second node command. Try it directly in the node command:

```
nohup node --max-old-space-size=256 --inspect ./bin/server.js >> ws.log 2>&1 &
nohup node --max-old-space-size=256 --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./bin/http_server.js >> http.log 2>&1 &
```

With this you can check what the heap size is during runtime:

```
console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapTotal);
```

Comment: I add the parameter but the memory still not increase. I am using prom-client + prometheus to monitor the node serivce.